# Specific user input to dataframe using scan

Tags: r

```
y <- as.numeric (readline(prompt="How many metabolites?: ")) # Get no. metabolites used 
x <- as.numeric (readline(prompt="How many concs?: ")) # Get no. concentrations of each metabolite used

print(paste("enter", y," metabolite names separated by return: ")) # User input for metabolite names
c <- scan(nmax=y,what = character())
```

Thus far we have captured the number of metabolites, the number of concentrations and the metabolite names.

```
print(paste("enter", x," numbers for metabolite x separated by return: "))
a <- scan(nmax=x,what=double())
df =  data.frame(conc=x,value=a)
```

This code captures x different metabolite concentrations. Any thoughts on how this can be extended to achieve?:

- capture x number of concs for y metabolites (the values of x will differ for different metabolites, but the number of values is constant).

Desired output assuming x = 5, y = 2 (user-specified conc values):

```
metabolite  conc1  conc2   conc3  conc4  conc5
metabolite1  100     10      1      0.1    0.001
metabolite2  10      1      0.1    0.01     0.001
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do it like this rather than reading in a csv which is far less tedious and less prone to error?

Comment: the raw .csv output  lacks this information. The rest of the workflow uses data directly from .csv . This script is for basic scientists that rely on hand written protocols. The .csv is verbose so this approach I think is best.

Comment: What do you mean by .csv output? You can create your own csv in a text editor, excel or the spread-sheet program on Mac/Linux. Just write the desire table into a csv and read that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you were hoping to do

```
y <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "How many metabolites?: "))
x <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "How many concs?: "))

print(paste("enter", y, " metabolite names separated by return: "))
c <- scan(nmax = y, what = character())

data <- matrix(nrow = x, ncol = y)

for (metab in 1:y) {
    print(paste("enter", x, " numbers for metabolite", c[metab], "separated by return: "))
    data[metab, ] <- scan(nmax = x, what = double())
}

df <- as.data.frame(data)
df <- cbind(c, df)
colnames(df) <- c("metabolite", paste0("conc", 1:x))
df
```

But I don't recommend doing this at all, instead you should generate a csv yourself so you have

***conc_data.csv***

```
metabolite,conc1,conc2,conc3,conc4,conc5
metabolite1,100,10,1,0.1,0.001
metabolite2,10,1,0.1,0.01,0.001
```

and in your code

```
df <- read.csv("conc_data.csv")
```

You can prepare the csv in excel by just filling it in and using `save as` then choosing CSV in the file type. Always open that csv file with a text editor to check excel hasn't inserted extra columns or rows.